# merge dataframes with row.names

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes which I am trying to `merge` using `row.names`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col11=c('v111', 'v112', 'v113'),
                  col12=c('v121', 'v122', 'v123'),
                  col13=c('v131', 'v132', 'v133'))
row.names(df1) <- c('rec1', 'rec2', 'rec3')

#      col11 col12 col13
# rec1  v111  v121  v131
# rec2  v112  v122  v132
# rec3  v113  v123  v133

df2 <- data.frame(col21=c('v213', 'v214'),
                  col22=c('v223', 'v224'))
row.names(df2) <- c('rec3', 'rec4')

#      col21 col22
# rec3  v213  v223
# rec4  v214  v224

dfM <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = 'row.names', all = T)

#   Row.names col11 col12 col13 col21 col22
# 1      rec1  v111  v121  v131  <NA>  <NA>
# 2      rec2  v112  v122  v132  <NA>  <NA>
# 3      rec3  v113  v123  v133  v213  v223
# 4      rec4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  v214  v224
```

the problem is that in the resulting data.frame `row.names` are converted to additional column `Row.names`, i.e. I have to run something like `row.names(dfM) <- dfM$Row.names; dfM$Row.names <- NULL;`. Is there any way to avoid this?

P.S. I would like to avoid this because in fact I am merging not just 2 dataframes but many, combined in a list:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2) # in fact my list contains many dataframes
dfM <- Reduce(function(x,y){merge(x, y, by='row.names', all=T)}, df_list)
```

to solve the problem of appearing Row.names, now I have to call `Reduce` in this way:

```
dfM <- Reduce(function(x,y){df <- merge(x, y, by='row.names', all=T);
                            row.names(df) <- df$Row.names; 
                            df$Row.names <- NULL;
                            df;
                            }, nrm_plates)
```

and I am just wondering if there's more elegant solution...

Comment: it's easy enough to remove the row.names column: `dfM$Row.names <- NULL`

Comment: If the row names are that important (as to contain information for merging) they should probably be columns from the beginning.

Comment: In addition to what @Jthorpe suggested, you can also simply do `row.names(dfM) <- dfM$Row.names` before you remove the row names.

Comment: Jthorpe, blakeoft - well, that's exactly what I said "I have to run something like this" in my question, but I would like to avoid this if it's possible (see PS added).